# how to redirect html into a url

Tags: web, modx

I am not sure if this is possible.

This is the name of the site: 
www.mysite.com

and I created an html  (named index.html) & saved it to the folder **myfile** which is a redirect to this site **www.mysite.com/myfile**

Now on the site, I have a content here that if you click on it, it will direct you to this: 
**www.mysite.com/documentation**

Now the redirect html I made, I would like it to be redirected to the documentation

so that if you click on www.mysite.com/myfile - it will open the www.mysite.com/documentation but this documentation is not an html its inside the cms.

Is that possible?

Btw here is the html code I saved in the index.html. Do I have to insert the url here: 
www.mysite.com/documentation?

> CONSTRUCTION PAGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.mysite.com/documentation">
```

I have trouble understanding your question correctly. So I am unsure if this will help you.

Edit for valid html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Redirect</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.mysite.com/documentation" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about it. But I think you still understood what I meant. ITs also difficult for me as I'm not familiar with the terminologies. This is what I did now. and it looks like it works but when I tried to validate this to this site: http://validator.w3.org/ I got 3 errors. Not sure if the html I have is wrong:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/documentation">
</head>
</html>

Comment: Why would you want to validate the redirect?

Comment: does it have a disadvantage? I was told that I need to validate. Is it necessary?

Comment: Its good practice yes. But a making a redirect valid is imho a little bit to thorough.

Comment: is it possible to redirect a site to a pdf file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6380/discussion-between-tintincutes-and-jarco)

Answer (score 1):

Use document type weblink on modx

Answer (score 1):

As Gus suggested, use a weblink.

Create a new weblink with alias **myfile**, and the content should be a link to **www.mysite.com/documentation**.

Then if you visit www.mysite.com/myfile it will take you directly to www.mysite.com/documentation.

For more info:  http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Weblink

Answer (score 1):

As the others have already said, a weblink in modX would be the way to go.

I [answered this already in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9023525/1062304) in your other question with essentially the same topic.