# is it possible to redirect a link to a pdf file

Tags: web, modx

is it possible to redirect a link to a pdf file?

This is my site: www.mysite.com

And I createad a redirect link that if I open www.mysite.com/documentation - an index.html file will open but for now this index.html file says it's under construction.

Can I redirect the link to a pdf file? 
I uploaded the pdf file into the server. So that if I open www.mysite.com/documentation, my pdf named as thedocument.pdf will open.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your web hosting provider won't allow you alter the default extensions (i.e. to add pdf) then you could create a HTML page to act as the landing page and then redirect to the PDF.

Details here: http://www.web-source.net/html_redirect.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Check your web server configuration that currently points /documentation to index.html, and change it to point to thedocument.pdf.

Be aware that the PDF may or may not load in the user's browser. Some configurations will prompt the user to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a modX [Weblink](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Weblink).

1. Upload your pdf to a place from where it is publicly downloadable. For this example I will upload it to `modx/assets/content/test.pdf`. You should now be able to download your file from `http://yourdomain.tld/assets/content/test.pdf`.
2. Create a new weblink resource in modX (Site -> New Weblink) on the base level of your resource-tree. Make it a container and type in 'documentation' as the alias of your resource. You should also make sure, that you already [use friendly urls](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Friendly+URLs), but your question sounds like you're already doing this.
3. A weblink has a field to enter the 'weblink' instead of the ressource content. Just use the URL from which you are already able to download your pdf-file. In this example, this would be `http://yourdomain.tld/assets/content/test.pdf`.
4. If you now view the newly created weblink resource under `http://yourdomain.tld/documentation`, you should instantly download a copy of your file test.pdf.